# TypeScript: Define a sub-type explicitly

Tags: typescript

Given type A, I want to define a sub-type B (B is assignable to A, without extra properties) and enforce that assign-ability.

#### Example

Given this type:

```
interface A {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

I want to define this type:

```
interface B {
  name: string;
}
```

As you can see, any instance of PersonDescriptor is assignable to Person, but it is not enforced. If I add another property, I would like typescript to complain.

#### Unacceptable solutions

1. I cannot use extend, since it will the resulted type will be less strict than what I intend:

```
interface B extends A {
  name: string;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
interface B {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

And also I can add properties that does not exist on Person.

2. I cannot do `A extends B` since A is already provided, and B is the type I want to create.

Comment: Share PersonDescriptor and PErson interface. For me, it is unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: try built-in Required<A>

Comment: Please either talk about `A` and `B` or `Person` and `PersonDescriptor` but not both, since the question as it stands is not clear.  Also it would be useful to provide a [mcve] of code that you'd like to see compile with no warning and code that you'd like to see compile with warnings.  It's not really possible in TypeScript to accurately express "without extra properties" since object types are intentionally open and extendible.  So if you could include an example of a use case where you'd like to see warnings, we can tell you if it's possible or not.  Without an example I have to just shrug.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want fields that *already exist in A*, you should consider using another approach, e.g.:

```js
type IsAssignable<X, Y extends X> = {
  [K in keyof Y]: K extends keyof X ? Y[K] : never;
}

type B = IsAssignable<A, { name: string; }>;
```

This wouldn't stop you from declaring

```js
type C = IsAssignable<A, {
  name: string;
  foo: number;
}>;

// C becomes { name: string; foo: never }
```

But it's still type-safe! Essentially, `IsAssignable<X,Y>` is telling typescript to ignore fields that aren't present in `X`. So any function that expects `A` should still accept `C` gladly;

Comment: Your solution is not ideal since in the event in adding the "foo" field, it's actually being added to C, but as type never. Which is perhaps impossible to assign correctly, but also impossible to figure out the error when occurs. Even though I managed to come up with a solution that removes the "foo" property entirely:

```
export type TIsAssignable<A, B extends A> = {
  [K in ({ [key in keyof B]: key extends keyof A ? key : never }[keyof B])]: B[K];
};
```

It's not ideal either because there will be no errors for the "foo" property